# Add text before and after a word in PHP

Tags: php

I have some quite big files i need to append some text to.
All files are built the same way, its only one word per line but there is 500.000 lines and words.

I tested to do this with awk in linux but dident really get it to work the way i wanted. And PHP would suit me better overall.

My biggest issue is that the text i want to append is " and ","" but when i try my script it thinks its a part of the script. This is what i want to do.

Example how it looks like before the append of text before and after the word

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
```

after convert i want it to be listed as.

```
   "word1",""
   "word2",""
   "word3",""
   "word4",""
```

and so on for all the lines and words in the file i input.

Comment: Your issue regarding `my script it thinks its a part of the script` is probably escaping. i.e. You're doing `""".$word."""` instead of `'"'.$word.'"'` ? What exactly have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on explode look at the following function:

```
<?php
function sandwitch($str){
   $output = "";
   $arr = explode("\n", $str);
   foreach ($arr as $word){
     $output .= '"'.trim($word)."\",\"\""."\n";
   }
 return $output;
}

$words = "word1
word2
word3
word4";

echo sandwitch($words);
```

Checkout this DEMO: http://codepad.org/L5J6TCwT

Answer (score 1):

Loop through each line using `fgets()` and make sure everything is quoted/escaped properly:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen($path_to_file);
$output = '';
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    $output .= '"' . $line . '",""' . "\n";
}
fclose($handle);
file_put_contents($output, $path_to_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$word[]='before';
$word[]= $content;
$word[]='after';
$word = join('',$word);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do that by linux command.

Adding prefix

```
sed -e 's/^/"/' file
```

then suffix

```
sed -e 's/$/",""/' file
```

Comment: Or just `sed -i 's/\(.*\)/"\1",""/' $file`

Comment: I tested both of your scripts and the second part always comes up as a new line so it looks like
"word
",""
"word
",""

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question but if you're asking about how to transform a string contained in a variable with the value word1 and add double quotes it's fairly simple, either use single quotes or escape the double quotes:

```
//pre-existing state
$value = "word1";

$value = "\"$value\",\"\"";
```

Hope this helps. An alternative would be:

```
$value = '"'.$value.',""';
```